# (Folhas de Cálculo/Google Docs) Preenchimento automático se célula estiver preenchida

Tags: microsoft-excel, google

[image: exemplo]

Basicamente, o que gostava de fazer era: 
Sempre que a pessoa 1 (p. exemplo) adicionasse uma data na tabela do lado esquerdo, o calendário do lado direito era preenchido autom. com o dia e a cor da pessoa. 
Seria necessário fazer um script?

Comment: Sim, seria necessário. Observe também que Excel != Google.